# Cronjob every 14 days on a friday (i. e. every second friday)

Tags: cron

I need to run a cronjob every 14 days on a friday i. e. every second friday.
Following is the closest I can think of:

```
0 10 */14 * 5
```

I think crontab would run this cronjob at 10:00 on the 14th and 28th day of a month (and that's not even every 14 days!) if this day is a friday. This condition would not be met every second friday, of course.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crontab does not support every other friday types of specification natively, but you could do something like this I suppose:

```
00 10 1-7,15-21 * * [ `date +\%a` = Fri ] && yourcommand
```

Comment: The day range is a good idea. Why are you checking for friday with shell scripting? Shouldn't `00 10 1-7,15-21 * 5` do the same?

Comment: I don't know, it would make sense indeed but I never tried that solution. I know for sure that /2 does not work for weekdays although that would have been the most logical solution in my view.

Comment: It looks like the values are not all restrictive. `00 10 1-7,15-21 * 5` ran 7 times between December 1 and 7. And additionally it runs on every friday.